# SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().calculateRoute without clearing previous route SKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps, maproute

How use SKRoutingService for calculateRoute without clearing previous route that i use for navigation
I just want know travel time for next rout but SKRoutingService clear my current rout that used for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate a route "in the background" then make the [shouldBeRendered](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.1/Classes/SKRouteSettings.html#//api/name/shouldBeRendered) parameter false - the route will be calculated but it won't be rendered on the map.

Comment: i actual use shouldBeRendered = false for calculating. But old calculated and rendered path disappear.

Comment: Indeed - you are correct. I'll investigate some more